# Display Modal Window in Middle of Method

Tags: macos, cocoa, modal-dialog, nswindow

So I have a program that after a try/catch block occurs I need a modal window to appear so the user can make a specific choice then I would like the program to continue on. I have no Idea how to make this work and I keep getting these exceptions.

```
*** Assertion failure in -[NSApplication _commonBeginModalSessionForWindow:relativeToWindow:modalDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo:], /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1187.34/AppKit.subproj/NSApplication.m:3920

Exception detected while handling key input.

Modal session requires modal window
```

I have configured my modal sheet to appear in 2 different ways the first way is Via a button press and the 2nd way is after my try catch block. When I make it appear Via a button press that is linked directly to `Configure Game` it works fine but when I do it through a try catch block in another method it throws all the exceptions above.

```
//Method that opens the modal sheet
- (IBAction)configureGame:(id)sender
{
    //Calls a webview for the user to go to a specific location   
    NSString *FGstarter = @"http://www.google.com";
    NSURL *FGplayerUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:FGstarter];        
    [webView setMainFrameURL:[FGplayerUrl absoluteString]];

    //Opens the Modal Sheet
    [NSApp beginSheet:configureSheet modalForWindow:mainWindow
        modalDelegate:self didEndSelector:NULL contextInfo:nil];

}

//Select Method to a Select button which also closes the Sheet
- (IBAction)select:(id)sender{
    //sets a NSString Instance Var to the Current URL of the webView
    currentPage = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location.href"]);

    //Closes the sheet
    [NSApp endSheet:configureSheet];     
}


-(NSMutableArray *)loadPlayer:(NSString *)name{
@try {
   // Code here might cause exception that gets caught in the catch
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    //When I call this function I get all the exceptions listed in the top of the post
    [self configureGame:nil];
    //Ideally here what would happen here is the modal sheet would pop up the user would hit the select button that calls the select method then the program continues running.  
}
   NSString *page = currentPage;
   //...Continue Using this method
}
```

Comment: Catch block code should be as simple as possible. You really want to avoid having to put try catch in a try catch. Only way to find out why you are is to step into it. Something is missing or stuffed because of the original exception at a guess, but seeing as you are catching generic exceptions that could almost anything.

Comment: Im pretty sure it has to do with the line `[self configureGame:nil];` which calls the `- (IBAction) configureGame:(id)sender` method, because even when delete the try catch block and just leave the line `[self configureGame:nil];` the program still throws all of the `Modal session requires modal window` and the other exceptions. Essentially my goal is to call the `- (IBAction) configureGame:(id)sender` method from another method in the program without an exception being thrown.

Comment: You aren't using exceptions for flow control, are you? In Cocoa, you should use exceptions only for situations where *you* screwed up—i.e., the program's state is no longer valid. You throw an exception to indicate this and catch it only to try to recover. Exceptions in Cocoa are the last resort before outright crashing or corrupting data.

Comment: No I'm not the catch is called by an index out of bounds exception that. I'm pretty sure that the `Modal session requires modal window` exceptions are not even related to the try catch block.

Comment: Well yes, but you messing with a symptom. You shouldn't be resolving an exception by chucking up forms and doing all sorts of complex stuff. Stop it happening, or detect the scenario.

Comment: I guess your right. Its a smarter solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't do this. From the Apple Docs...

> **Important** In many environments, use of exceptions is fairly commonplace. For example, you might throw an exception to signal that a routine could not execute normally—such as when a file is missing or data could not be parsed correctly. Exceptions are resource-intensive in Objective-C. You should not use exceptions for general flow-control, or simply to signify errors. Instead you should use the return value of a method or function to indicate that an error has occurred, and provide information about the problem in an error object. For more information, see Error Handling Programming Guide.

See also the top answer to this question:
[When porting Java code to ObjC, how best to represent checked exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117384/when-porting-java-code-to-objc-how-best-to-represent-checked-exceptions)